# Que tipo de testes ainda posso fazer nesse código?

Tags: java, testes, junit

Estou fazendo uma sequência de testes em um aplicativo simples de banco, porém eu não sei mais que tipo de teste posso fazer nesse sistema pra cobrir 100% do código, só está cobrindo 61%. Jà fiz todos os testes com valores inferiores, iguais e superiores, fiz com identificação anônima e identificada, fiz com identificação anônima identificada com valor inferior, mas não sei qual tipo de teste fazer pra ter 100% da cobertura do código.

http://pastebin.com/EABxW0SH

Os códigos não couberam na pergunta, por isso postei no pastebin.org

Classe das Regras

```
RegrasDepositoEnum.java

    package facema.regras;

    import java.math.BigDecimal;

    import facema.modelo.operacional.Deposito;
    import facema.util.StringUtils;

    public enum RegrasDepositoEnum {

        /**
         * O banco não aceita depósitos anônimos, portanto nome e CPF
         * do depositante devem ser fornecidos.
         *
         */
        DADOS_DEPOSITANTE() {
                @Override
                public boolean aplicavel(Deposito deposito) throws Exception {
                        String cpf = deposito.getDepositante().getCpf();
                        String nome = deposito.getDepositante().getNome();

                        if (StringUtils.isStringVazia(cpf) || StringUtils.isStringVazia(nome)) {
                                return false;
                        } else {
                                return true;
                        }
                }
        },

        /**
         * O valor mínimo para depósito é R$ 1,00
         * Depósitos com valores inferiores a este não serão realizados.
         * Retorna false caso o depósito tenha valor inferior a R$ 1,00, então o depósito não pode ser efetuado.
         * Retorna true em caso contrário e o depósito poderá ser efetuado.
         *
         */
        VALOR_MINIMO() {
                @Override
                public boolean aplicavel(Deposito deposito) throws Exception {
                        BigDecimal valor = deposito.getValor();

                        if (valor.compareTo(new BigDecimal("1")) < 0) {
                                return false;
                        } else {
                                return true;
                        }
                }
        };

        public abstract boolean aplicavel(Deposito deposito) throws Exception;

    }

RegrasSaqueEnum.java

    package facema.regras;

    import java.math.BigDecimal;

    import facema.modelo.banco.Conta;
    import facema.modelo.operacional.Saque;

    public enum RegrasSaqueEnum {


        /**
         * Valida se o valor do saque é maior que zero.
         * Retorna true se passar na regra.
         * Retorna false em caso contrário.
         */
        VALIDACAO_VALOR() {
                @Override
                public boolean aplicavel(Saque saque) throws Exception {
                        BigDecimal valor = saque.getValor();

                        if (valor.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) > 0) {
                                return true;
                        } else {
                                return false;
                        }
                }
        },

        /**
         * Limite de R$ 200,00 por dia para saque em uma conta
         * Retorna true se passar na regra.
         * Retorna false em caso contrário.
         */
        LIMITE_DIARIO() {
                @Override
                public boolean aplicavel(Saque saque) throws Exception {
                        Conta conta = saque.getConta();
                        BigDecimal valor = saque.getValor();
                        BigDecimal limite = new BigDecimal("200.00");
                        BigDecimal saqueHoje = conta.getSaqueHoje();

                        BigDecimal saqueTotal = saqueHoje.add(valor);

                        int saqueMaiorLimite = saqueTotal.compareTo(limite);
                        if (saqueMaiorLimite > 0) {
                                return false;
                        } else {
                                return true;
                        }
                }
        },

        /**
         * O valor do saque não pode exceder o valor que o cliente possui na conta
         * Retorna true se passar na regra.
         * Retorna false em caso contrário.
         */
        LIMITE_CONTA() {
                @Override
                public boolean aplicavel(Saque saque) throws Exception {
                        Conta conta = saque.getConta();
                        BigDecimal valor = saque.getValor();

                        int saqueMaiorLimite = valor.compareTo(conta.getSaldo());
                        if (saqueMaiorLimite > 0) {
                                return false;
                        } else {
                                return true;
                        }
                }
        };

        public abstract boolean aplicavel(Saque saque) throws Exception;

    }

RegrasExtratoEnum.java

    package facema.regras;

    import java.util.Date;

    import facema.modelo.operacional.Extrato;

    public enum RegrasExtratoEnum {

        /**
         * Cliente pode solicitar extrato de um período máximo de
         * 1 ano da data inicial até a data final.
         * Caso o intervalo enre as datas inicial e final seja maior que 1 ano, retorna false e o extrato não pode ser fornecido.
         * Caso contrário, retorn true e o extrato é realizado.
         *
         */
        PERIODO_1_ANO() {
                @Override
                public boolean aplicavel(Extrato extrato) throws Exception {
                        Date dataInicial = extrato.getDataFinal();
                        Date dataFinal = extrato.getDataInicial();

                        long dif = Math.abs(dataFinal.getTime() - dataInicial.getTime());
                        long difDias = dif / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

                        if (difDias > 365) {
                                return false;
                        } else {
                                return true;
                        }
                }

        },

        /**
         * O cliente tem direito a 1 extrato mensal gratuito
         * Verifica se o cliente já tirou algum extrato naquela conta gratuitamente no mês corrente.
         * Em caso positivo, o teste retorna false e o extrato deve ser cobrado.
         * Em caso negativo, o teste retorna true e o extrato deve ser gratuito.
         */
        EXTRATO_MENSAL_GRATUITO() {
                @Override
                public boolean aplicavel(Extrato extrato) throws Exception {
                        if (extrato.getConta().getExtratosMes() == 0) {
                                return true;
                        } else {
                                return false;
                        }
                }
        };

        public abstract boolean aplicavel(Extrato extrato) throws Exception;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

A cobertura de código verifica se todos os caminhos do seu código foram percorridos. Isso inclui verificar todos os desvios condicionais.

Por exemplo:

```
if (valor.compareTo(new BigDecimal("1")) < 0) {
  return false;
} else {
  return true;
}
```

Seus testes devem cobrir tanto o caso verdadeiro, como o falso.

Tentei verificar seu código, porém você não incluiu todas as classes de seu sistema na pergunta.

Uma boa ferramenta para verificar a cobertura dos testes sobre seu código é o [JaCoCo](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/). A ferramenta gera um relatório mostrando qual parte do código está coberta ou não. Ela também adiciona cores nas linhas de sua IDE, facilitando a verificação.

[image: Cores nas linhas da IDE (NetBeans).]

As linhas vermelhas mostram linhas de código sem cobertura de testes unitários. As linhas verdes são códigos que estão cobertos por testes.

[image: Relatório sobre a cobertura dos testes sobre todas as classes do pacote.]

Relatório sobre a cobertura dos testes sobre todas as classes do pacote. É possível observar que algumas classes não estão cobertas, enquanto outras tem cobertura parcial.

Por último, vale lembrar que cobertura apenas significa que o código foi executado. Não garante que o código foi testado de fato. Para criar testes eficazes, você precisa criar asserções que verifiquem se os métodos e as classes executam da forma esperada.

**Atualização**

Consegui executar seu projeto no Eclipse. Algumas considerações.

A ferramenta JaCoCo tem vários tipos de cobertura de código. Cobertura por instruções byte code, por desvios condicionais, por complexidade ciclomática, por linhas de código, por métodos executados e por classes instanciadas.

Você pode alterar qual tipo de cobertura será utilizado, conforme a imagem abaixo.

[image: Cobertura de código.]

Conforme a imagem acima, é possível verificar que sua cobertura por linhas de código está quase em 100%. Nessa tela de visualização, você pode selecionar outras métricas e atualizar seus testes. Verifiquei aqui e alguns testes estão faltando. Dê uma olhada no relatório gerado no Eclipse.

Vale lembrar que a cobertura de instruções, ou byte code, não apresenta uma métrica de cobertura confiável. Conforme o JaCoCo: "Not all Java language constructs can be directly compiled to corresponding byte code. In such cases the Java compiler creates so called synthetic code which sometimes results in unexpected code coverage results."

Isto é, algumas construções de Java não são diretamente transformadas em byte code. O código gerado não é coberto, gerando inconsistências no resultado de cobertura.

Utilize métricas como chamada de métodos, linhas executadas ou complexidade ciclomática. Assim, seu percentual de cobertura ficará de acordo com suas expectativas.

Comment: O Eclemma muda as cores Bernardo, achei que com a classe das regras dava pra entender.

Comment: Todas as linhas do seu código estão verdes?

Comment: Sim. Não sei mais que tipo de teste pode ser feito nele.

Comment: O relatório mostra cobertura 100%? Onde você está vendo apenas 61% de cobertura? É possível que a ferramenta não esteja calculando corretamente, algumas vezes esse tipo de coisa acontece.

Comment: Vou enviar as outra classes.

Comment: Vou copiar para o dropbox pra você ver, são muitas classes.

Comment: Olha aí! https://www.dropbox.com/sh/07y16ghjr5bz6oo/AADlMFKHdMa_yMXs2rciKDxia?dl=0

Comment: Atualizei a resposta, dê uma olhada.

Comment: Você executou no JaCoCo?

Comment: Sim, executei no JaCoCo.

Answer (score 1):

Seguem algumas sugestões:

Em DADOS_DEPOSITANTE(): experimentou colocar CPF invalido no valor, porém valido na estrutura? Exemplo 999.999.999.99, experimente fazer isso com o "0" pois nem todas as mascaras tratam o CPF com 11 "0".
Testou o input de letras no lugar do CPF.
Testou o tamanho do campo do nome? Quantos caracteres ele aguenta.
Testou preencher o campo nome com espaços, apertando a barra de espaço? Não sera valor nulo, apenas valor em branco, esse erro quase nenhum programador trata.

VALOR_MINIMO(): Testou valor negativo? Letras? Caracteres especiais?

Só de olhar este código, minha mente pipocou de testes que podem ser efetuados...Experimente colocar uma tag html nos campos e teclar enter e por ai vai.

Comment: BigDecimal não aceita letras Paulo.